# What does "sweet spot" mean?

Tags: meaning

Not the sport definition, but this one:

> In our survey, the **sweet spot** for Windows are organizations with 300
>   to 1000 employees.

Comment: A sweet spot is ["a location or combination of characteristics that produces the best results"](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/sweet+spot)

Comment: General Reference. This is in [lots of dictionaries](http://onelook.com/?w=sweet+spot).

Comment: @MετάEd: From all the 15+ references you posted: Merriam, Dictionary.com, etc. only Wordnik and Wiktionary offer the meaning I'm asking here... I obviously searched before coming here. Not easy to find...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the area at which different factors balance out to give an optimal result. In this sentence, organisations below 300 do not benefit as much as those above that number, while also organisations above 1000 doe not benefit as much as those below it; so 300–1000 is the "sweet spot".

More formally, we might say that it was the optimum range.

The origin is probably from sports, particularly racket or bat sports where there's a "sweet spot" that the ball should ideally be hit with, then expanding into other sporting uses, before becoming a more general phrase.

Answer (score 4):

According to the context of the sentence you presented, "sweet spot" is related to the point or situation where the best or optimal results can be achieved.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much the same as the sport meaning - the **optimal** size of organisation for Windows was ...

Answer (score 3):

In circumstances where a desirable characteristic varies continuously, the *sweet spot* describes the point (or the region) of a local maximum. The term cannot be used in cases of a local minimum or where there is uninterrupted rise or fall in the variable.

So when you consider the point of contact of the ball along a bat, the sweet spot is the point from which the hit travels further or faster than from a point on either side.

When you are recommending adoption of a software solution, the sweet point is the size of organisation that receives the greatest return on investment.

Answer (score 0):

There is a diagram describing it as well:

[image: Sweet Spot]

Best state!

Comment: What if more is always better for a given quality? Incidentally, you can include images in answers, rather than ask people to follow links.

Comment: @ Jon :)) Surely you are right! Thanks for nice advice!

Comment: You could also provide a link to cite the source of the image.