# Another Word for "Sweet Spot"

Tags: single-word-requests

On google the definition of "sweet spot" has to do with a tennis racket. I'm looking for a broader more general term, maybe it's an idiom in our culture, there's no denying that *Sweet Spot* means a harmonious balance for just about anything. Can you give me another word for this?

Comment: Self-confessed "phrasedick" William Saffire says [that the origin of the metaphor is the thickest part of a baseball bat. That may not be subtle enough; more precisely, it is the place somewhere on the “meat end” of the bat that the batter believes gives him the most power and control of placement.](http://www.nytimes.com/2007/04/01/magazine/01wwln-safire.t.html)

Comment: In many contexts, something like *the Goldilocks zone* might convey the same sense.

Comment: How about ***the*** *spot*?  Perhaps it would help to understand what’s wrong with *sweet spot* and how you intend to use this word.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's one general term or idiom. The concept of an optimal point, or an optimum, has inspired many words, phrases, and idioms.

Here are a couple.

**(1) That [really] hit the spot.**

[The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hit+the+spot) defines it this way:

> **hit the spot**
>
> to be exactly what is wanted or needed

We usually use it when referring to food. For example, "That pumpkin pie really hit the spot."

---

**(2) Hit the bull's eye.**

[The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hit+the+bull's-eye) defines it this way:

> **hit the bull's-eye**
>
> 1. to hit the very center of a circular target.
> 2. to achieve the goal perfectly.

An example would be, "You really hit the bull's eye with your essay on U.S. politics."

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but the big font makes me feel like you're shouting.

Comment: Pumpkin pie does hit the spot -- but that has nothing to do with the "sweet spot."

Comment: @aparente001 Are these comments even necessary? You sound like one of the hostile ELU users who just wants to prove that he/she is better than others through snarky comments.

Comment: No hostility intended, and I am sorry my comments came across that way.  But would you rather I downvoted with no explanation?  Please do not hesitate to raise a flag when you see a not-nice comment or answer.  That will bring it to a moderator's attention.

Comment: @aparente001 The big font came about because I used the # character. I was trying to enumerate my two examples, and I accidentally discovered that it increases the font. I chose to keep it.

Comment: I don't know how others would react.  My subjective reaction was that it felt kind of in-your-face.  It might just be me.

Comment: @aparente001 I also disagree with your reasoning. I was simply reframing his question as one about finding the optimum. [That's what the sweet spot is all about.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103567/what-does-sweet-spot-mean) I said that there's no **one general term** but there are many examples inspired by this idea of finding the optimum. Then I gave a couple examples. I think this makes for a useful answer, if not the best answer.

Comment: But I admit that you have a point. It's certainly not the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

> there's no denying that Sweet Spot means a harmonious balance for just
>   about anything.

I am not sure about the "anything" part. In sports, *sweet spot* is:

> a place where a combination of factors results in a maximum response
>   for a given amount of effort.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_spot_%28sports%29

The term is also used in [acoustics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_spot_%28acoustics%29) and in [phonetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonation#State_of_the_glottis). If you want a generic term, I would suggest ***optimal configuration***.

> **optimal**
>   best or most favorable; optimum : *seeking the optimal solution*.
>
> New Oxford American Dictionary

Answer (score -1):

***perfect balance***

Here is an example:  String players find that there is a sweet spot in terms of the bow's distance from the bridge.  If you get too close to the bridge, your tone could be raspy; if you don't get close enough, your tone will be wimpy and won't project.  The *zone of perfect balance* is rather wide when you are playing in first position, because the freely vibrating portion of the string is very long.  But when you're in a high position, for example fifth position (violin/viola) or thumb position (cello, bass), the vibrating portion of the string is much shorter, so the zone of perfect balance is much narrower, and you have to *hit it right on the nail* in order to get an effective sound.

When you don't resort to using the phrase "sweet spot," you must explain the trade-offs involved quite clearly.